# How to change text colour when text box clicked in Macro enabled Powerpoint 2013?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I would like the text to change colour from grey to black... How do I do this on Powerpoint 2013 and where would I apply the code? Sorry in advance for not supplying any code I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself...

NOTE: You have to set the ForeColor to a certain color before you begin the Slideshow Presentation.

This example shows how to change the preset color to black

```html
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
    TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

.